# System.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred while parsing the input string - Blob.toPdf

Tags: apex, email, salesforce1-app, apex-email-service, blob.topdf

Trying to convert inbound email to Blob PDF and adding to Document File, Below is the code.

When i ran the below code getting this error `**FATAL_ERROR System.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred while parsing the input string.**`

```
public with sharing class EmailServiceController implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler  {
    
    public Messaging.InboundEmailResult  handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                            Messaging.InboundEnvelope env)
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        
        string emailBodyText = email.htmlBody;
        Blob pdfContent = Blob.toPdf(emailBodyText);
        system.debug('pdfContent');

 List<ContentVersion>cverList = new list<ContentVersion>();
            string documentName = 'Email to Approver1.pdf';          
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            cv.VersionData = pdfContent;
            cv.Title = documentName;
            cv.PathOnClient = documentName; 
            cverList.add(cv);
            insert cverList; 

contentversion  cvlist;
            if(  
                contentversion.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
                    cvlist = [select id, contentdocumentid, Title from contentversion where Id =:cverList];
                }
            list<Id> contentDocList = new list<Id>();
            List<ContentDistribution> cdlist = new list<ContentDistribution>();
            ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
            cd.Name = cvlist.Title;
            cd.ContentVersionId = cvlist.id;
            cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser= true;
            cd.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion=true;
            cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit=false;
            cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired=false;
            cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload= true;   
            cdlist.add(cd);
            contentDocList.add(cvlist.contentdocumentid);
            
            SObjectAccessDecision securityDecisioncdlist = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.CREATABLE, cdlist);        
            insert securityDecisioncdlist.getRecords();

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using the developer console this generates a `System.InvalidParameterValueException`:

```
Blob b = Blob.toPdf('');
```

and the [InboundEmail Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm) documentation says the HTML form may not always be present:

> **htmlBody**
> The HTML version of the email, if specified by the sender.

so for that case fall back on the plain text:

> **plainTextBody** 
> he plain text version of the email, if specified by the
> sender.

and if that also isn't present you can supply your own "Email body empty" string.